# Removing Firmware from a tablet

Tags: device-firmware

I purchased a NeuTab Tablet with an AllWinner Quad core cpu.  It appears to be rooted already but there doesn't seem to be a away to upgrade to a newer version of Android or at first glance to even flash CyanogenMod.

Is there a way to get rid of/unlock the firmware that's on there without bricking the device?

Answer (score -1):

You can manually update the firmware using Odin. Find the firmware you want to install. Try www.xdadevelopers.com and search for firmwares and various other Roms that "might" be available for your tablet.

Comment: Odin only works on Samsung devices.

Comment: Did not know that. Thanks for the information.